# Увидеть на/в записи

Tags: предлоги

Увидеть на/в записи — возможны ли оба варианта?

Answer (score 1):

Да, в разных контекстах. "В записи" — это не в живую. Скажем, не могу посмотреть прямой эфир, но потом увижу всё в записи. А "на записи" мы видим искажения, помехи и т.д.
Другими словами, "В записи" мы говорим, когда мысль отталкивается от события, которое будет записано. "На записи" мы говорим, когда мысль отталкивается от самой записи, и мы уже уточняем, что именно на ней увидели.

Answer (score 1):

Выбор зависит от контекста. Если это видеозапись, то "(увидеть) **в** записи" означает "*в записанном виде*" (а не в реальном времени - на экране или непосредственно); можно сказать: "***на*** записи" (на этой записи) видны такие-то особенности (ситуации или редактирования).